# How to make jQuery hover events not queue up?

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, mouseevent

I have a div that when I hover over it, a div inside it animates, and then when I stop hovering, it animates back to its original position. But if I hover over it multiple times, very quickly, then the animations queue up and continue until they are finished. Example: I quickly hover over the div 10 times quickly, and the div animates 10 times while I just sit there. I don't want these animations to queue up like this.

Here is my script:

```
$(".call1").hover(
    function(){
        $(".call-label").animate({"bottom": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    },
    function(){
        $(".call-label").animate({"bottom": "-=50px"}, "slow");    
    }
);​
```

I have a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem I am having: [http://jsfiddle.net/mqpbm/](http://jsfiddle.net/mqpbm/1/)

I have also tried .mouseover and .mouseout, and .mouseenter and .mouseleave. All of them do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(".call1").hover(
    function(){
        $(".call-label").stop().animate({"bottom": "50px"}, "slow");
    },
    function(){
        $(".call-label").stop().animate({"bottom": "0px"}, "slow");    
    }
);​
```

Comment: Using stop is the best practice. However `-=50px` and `+=50px` makes it stoppable at an unknown px value. Using `0px` and `50px` makes it better. http://jsfiddle.net/mqpbm/9/

Comment: When I use .stop(), the div.call-label tends to get thrown off its intended positioning. Any suggestions on how to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the hoverIntent plugin in the past to make the hover more responsive to users actual intentions. It should be useful for your purposes.

[hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)